# Wake on lan with suspend - Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, suspend, wakeup, wakeonlan

I'm using an Ubuntu server 20.04 and I've set up the wake on lan.
Everything is working fine when I shutdown the computer, I can wake it. But when I suspend it : impossible to wake it by the lan.
Have anyone ever had this issue ?
If someone have a solution, you're very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Wake-on-LAN feature is a hardware setting rather than something the OS controls, so it *technically* makes sense that the machine remains suspended when receiving the magic packet. That said, it can be quite bothersome for people who want their servers to wake and return to operation.

First, let’s confirm that the driver used for the network card supports WoL. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo ethtool <interface>
```

***Note:** Be sure to replace* `<interface>` *with the name of your device. If you’re not sure what the name is,* `ip link show` *will provide the interface name.*

The output should look something like this:

```
Settings for enp0s31f6:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Check the value of `Wake-on` contains a letter *that is not* `d`. If it does, this means to wake the machine, it needs to receive a "MagicPacket" rather than something else. There are several different options that the machine might be listening for. A complete list can be found [in the documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/ethtool.8.html) (search for the string `Wake-on-LAN options`).

If the value is `d`, this means the Wake-on value is disabled. If this is the case, you can enable it with this command:

```
sudo ethtool -s <interface> wol g
```

`-s` means "set", `<interface>` is the network interface, `wol` is "Wake on LAN", and `g` is "MagicPacket". You can choose other wake options as well, which are documented in the link above.

Unfortunately this command will need to be run every time your system boots, so be sure to add it to an appropriate startup script, such as part of the `up` rules in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Hope this gives you the info you need to have your machines wake up from suspend.

Comment: I've done all this already. And it's working when the computer is shutdown but not when it's suspended. Have I missed something ??

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I did:

```
sudo systemctl suspend
```

instead of:

```
systemctl suspend
```